# generate dates after groupby in pandas

Tags: pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby, date-range

I want to generate date at hourly level between start and end date. My input data looks like this :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gzn26.png) and my expected output is this : [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XEdm3.png). I have written the following code :

```
def func(grouped_df) : 
    start_date,  end_date = grouped_df['Start'][0], grouped_df['End'][0]
    df = pd.DataFrame()
    df['Duration'] = pd.date_range(start_date, end_date, freq='1h')
    df["Start"] = grouped_df['Start'][0]
    df["End"] = grouped_df['End'][0]
    return df

res = df.groupby('group').apply(func)
res
```

Comment: Please provide a dataframe sample, the output obtained and the expected output

Comment: Can you make please your question clearer? the duration column corresponds to what exactly in the expected output ?  What does `Prod_Run` correspond to ? is it the column you want to group by ?

Comment: I have edited questions, I have attached the image for input and expected output.